# Function .filter() in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

There is `JSON` called by `fetch()` request looks like this:

```
[{
"Info": "",
"Val": "3"
},
{
"Info": "",
"Val": "5"
},
{
"Info": "",
"Val": "1"
},
{
"Info": "",
"Val": "1"
}]
```

My purpose is to filter data according a filed called `Val`.

```
 library = library.filter(item =>
             item.Val==FilterVal
 )
```

Let me make an example to explain what I want to do.
Look at this input :`<input value={this.state.FilterVal} onChange={this.handlerFilter} />`

`FilterVal` is going to be a number for example `1` or some numbers separated by comma `1,5,4` .
For example user types `1` on input ,the result must return the objects that `Val`is `1`. For the next time type `1,5,4`must return me the objects that `Val` are `1` and `5` and `4`.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
  class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        library: null,
        FilterVal: "",

    }
}
componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/json.bc', {
            method: 'POST',
        })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => {
                const Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
                 this.setState(state => ({
                    ...state,
                    data: Maindata
                }), () => {
                    this.reorganiseLibrary()
                })
            }).catch(error => console.error(error))
    })
}
reorganiseLibrary = () => {
    const { FilterVal} = this.state;
    let library = data;
    if (FilterVal !== "") {
        library = library.filter(item =>
             item.Val==FilterVal
        )
    }
    library = _.chunk(library);
    this.setState({
        library
    })

}

handlerFilter = evt =>
    this.setState(
        {
            FilterVal: evt.target.value
        },
        () => {
            this.reorganiseLibrary();
        }
    )
renderLibrary = () => {
const { library} = this.state;
    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
        return <div>nodata</div>
    }
return library.map((item, i) => (
        <div>
                  <span>{item.name}</span>
                  <span>{item.Val}</span>
       </div>
    ))
}

render() {
    const { library} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
         {this.renderLibrary()}
         <input value={this.state.FilterVal} onChange={this.handlerFilter} />
      </div>
    )
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'))
```

Comment: Sorry but what is the question? Is your code not working? What's the current error or behavior?

Comment: Hi @ keul. Main problem is how to filter data based on `{this.state.FilterVal}`. For example `FilterVal = 1` so result is objects of `JSON` that field `Val` for them is `1`,but I want when `FilterVal =1,2` result will include objects of `JSON` that field `Val` for them are `1` and `2`.Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FilterVal.includes(item.Val)`. This is working solution.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      library: null,
      FilterVal: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var originalArray = [
      {
        Info: "",
        Val: "3"
      },
      {
        Info: "",
        Val: "3"
      },
      {
        Info: "",
        Val: "2"
      },
      {
        Info: "",
        Val: "4"
      },
      {
        Info: "",
        Val: "4"
      },
      {
        Info: "",
        Val: "5"
      },
      {
        Info: "",
        Val: "2"
      },
      {
        Info: "",
        Val: "1"
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ data: originalArray });
  }
  reorganiseLibrary = () => {
    let FilterVal = this.state.FilterVal;
    let library = this.state.data;
    if (FilterVal !== "") {
      FilterVal = FilterVal.split("");
      library = library.filter(item => {
        if (FilterVal.includes(item.Val)) return item;
      });
    } else {
      library = null;
    }
    // library = _.chunk(library);
    this.setState({
      library
    });
  };

  handlerFilter = evt =>
    this.setState(
      {
        FilterVal: evt.target.value
      },
      () => {
        this.reorganiseLibrary();
      }
    );
  renderLibrary = () => {
    const { library } = this.state;
    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
      return <div>nodata</div>;
    }
    return library.map((item, i) => (
      <div>
        <span>{item.name}</span>
        <span>{item.Val}</span>
      </div>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    const { library } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderLibrary()}
        <input value={this.state.FilterVal} onChange={this.handlerFilter} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("Result"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='Result' />
```

Comment: I have a question.Can we split `FilterVal` based on `,` because when I want to use this filter for something else not just a number it wont work correctly

Comment: For example I want to use `FilterVal` to filter data based on `Info` field of `JSON` and `Info` can be something like this :`B.B` or even a text such as `test text` by space.

Comment: `var originalArray = [
          {
            Info: "Accommodation only",
            Val: "3"
          },
          {
            Info: "B.B",
            Val: "3"
          },

          {
            Info: "B.B",
            Val: "4"
          },
          {
            Info: "R.O",
            Val: "4"
          },
          {
            Info: "R.O",
            Val: "5"
          },
          {
            Info: "B.B",
            Val: "2"
          },
          {
            Info: "Accommodation only",
            Val: "1"
          }
        ]`

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust your filter:

```
const values = FilterVal.split(',').map(v => Number(v))
library = library.filter(item => values.includes(item.Val))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work correctly.For example `FilterVal` is `2,3,4,5,`. The result is                                                                     `1
3
2
4
4`                                                                                                                            Firstly there is not `1` in `FilterVal` so why it is in result and next for getting objects of `Val=5`, `FilterVal`  should contain another number after  `5, `